# Node.js process consume much CPU in some ASP.NET Core project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I want to edit any of *cshtml files of some ASP.NET Core project, it will start Node.js process that consume too much CPU resources all time during the work.

[image]

But I don't have this problem with all ASP.NET Core projects. What I should improve or repair on projects, that starting Node.js process with high CPU consuming?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some solutions and threads about this.
See:

[Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27033/nodejs-server-side-javascript-process-consuming-to.html) on the VS dev site

and

David Yardly's post [Here](https://www.davidyardy.com/blog/node.js%20server-side%20javascript%20process%20consuming%20too%20much%20memory/), which refers back to the first link.

Check if you are using Typescript. Disabling the TypeScript extension may be a work around.

Comment: You should summarize the links since they can be obsoleted someday.

Comment: Once thing that helped me is, that I turned off JavaScript language service and disabled dedicated syntax process. Both options are placed in Tools->Options->Text Editor->JavaScript/TypeScript->LanguageService

Comment: I am not using TypeScript extension. Also tsconfig.json file not helped me.